# Как получить ключ array

Tags: php

Есть массив

```
Array ( [44] => Array ( [pageName] => Основная версия [pageMeta] => main [betaId] => ) )
```

Как получить число 44 в переменную?

Comment: `foreach ($array as $key => $value) {...}` или [`array_keys`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-keys.php) пойдет?

Answer (score 1):

например так

```
$key = key($array);
```

Comment: только перед этим `reset()` не забыть сделать

Answer (score 0):

Вариантов много. Можно через цикл `foreach`. Можно выбрать все ключи из массива `array_keys()`, после чего первый элемент значения будет 44. Можно `key()`. Можно `array_flip()` перевернуть местами и выбрать первый `current()`.

Все упирается в дальнейшее условие